# Django-Social-Auth Facebook doesn't save user's details

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

I'm using the basic Django-Social-Auth Facebook code to sign up via Facebook. for some reason, I can't get it to save the user's email, first and last name. it saves the username as the user's first+middle+last but the other attributes stay blank. I tried requesting the email address, and the app does say that we get the email address, but nothing saved to the tables.

I read all the posts and blogs about the Facebook sign up, but nothing seems to work for me. Am I missing something?

in settings.py I have:

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS  = ['email']
SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'social_auth',
)
```

I was looking at auth\models.py, and maybe the create_user function doesn't get the email field.

```
def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False,
                             **extra_fields)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this same issue before, So you need to create a pipeline in your settings.py to update facebook user data.
This code will help you to get facebook user data;
http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html

```
def update_user_social_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['user']
    if not kwargs['is_new']:
        return
    user = kwargs['user']
    if kwargs['backend'].__class__.__name__ == 'FacebookBackend':
        fbuid = kwargs['response']['id']
        access_token = kwargs['response']['access_token']

        url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/' \
              '?fields=email,gender,name' \
              '&access_token={1}'.format(fbuid, access_token,)

        photo_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" \
            % kwargs['response']['id']
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        email = json.loads(response).get('email')
        name = json.loads(response).get('name')
        gender = json.loads(response).get('gender')
```

Comment: so I need to add this code in the settings.py file? the variable as not being used and I'm getting error in urllib2 and json objects.

Comment: write this code and add this function to pilpeline settings.

Comment: where I need to write the code you provided? In which file? I'm new to Django :)

Comment: you will be having one pipeline settings in settings.py file.

Comment: Create a new file and add this function and give file path in pipeline settings

Comment: Okay. I think I got it. Is there a way to see the entire response that comes back from facebook? It doesn't save the first and last name as well.

Comment: end of the function, print json.loads(response) , so you can see the response.

Answer (score 0):

As in July, 2017 you have to place these lines into your settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
  'fields': 'id, name, email, age_range'
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '2.9' # or whatever version you're using
```

Hope this helps